# R: How to generate data frames from all the possible combination of three columns?

Tags: combinations, permutation

I have the following data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4), x2=c(10,20,30,40), x3=c(100,200,300,400))
```

And I want to generate al the possible data frames that can be created from combining `d1$x1`, `df1$x2` and `df1$x3` in different orders so `4^3` different dataframes, e.g:

```
 x1 x2 x3   
1  1  10 100  
2  2  20 200  
3  3  30 300  
4  4  40 400`  

   x1 x2 x3 
1  1  40  400  
2  2  30  300  
3  3  20  200  
4  4  10  100
```

and so on. For each of them I want to compute the following function:

```
my.function <- function(x1, x2, x3) { 
  sum(0.3*x1^2+0.3*x2^2+0.4*x3)/nrow(x1)
}
```

I did this, but it's clearly wrong:

```
res1 <- rep(NA, nrow(df1)^3)
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df1)){
    for(k in 1:nrow(df1)){
      x1.1 <- as.vector(c(df1[-i, 1], df1[i, 1]))
      x2.1 <- as.vector(c(df1[-k, 2], df1[k, 2]))
      x3.1 <- as.vector(c(df1[-j, 3], df1[j, 3]))
      res1[nrow(df1)^2*(i-1) + nrow(df1)*(j-1)+k] <- m.function(x1.1, x2.1, x3.1)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to find a similar problem of mine without much luck, could you please help me?
Thank you so much!!!